# Some programes not starting at windows starup

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I have a programme "Word Web Dictionary" and it used to start at windows startup every time I restarted or turned my computer on. Recently I came to know that it is not starting anymore, So I launched the programme manually and checked the option of running on Windows startup, and I found that it was greyed out!

[image]

Then, I ran it again as "run as administrator" and this time the option was not greyed out and the option was checked!

[image]

I thought my problem was solved now, but it wasn't!

I tried the following methods:

- Re-installing the software. Didn't work
- checking the "run as administrator" in the properties of the EXE file. Didn't work

How should I overcome this problem?

Comment: Have you tried putting a shortcut of the program in the Startup folder in the Start Menu?

Comment: there is already a shortcut. @MC10

Comment: I checked. It is empty. But I am on Windows 7 @MC10

Comment: Is there a shortcut already or is it empty? Create a shortcut of that program and move it to the Startup folder. Restart and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! THANKS A LOT ! :D  But please, can you tell me why this happened?

Comment: The tick box you're clicking is something they've programmed in their software. It may not work because it's written incorrectly, or needs to be run as an administrator, or it's not updated for your version of Windows, or you've got other software blocking it. Adding the shortcut to start up is another way to make software start once the user has logged on, bypassing the method it was trying to use.